# How to resolve AWS CDK error "Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFunction'"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I want to get the following example code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/serverless_example.html working, but I get a "Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFunction'" error.

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import * as apigateway from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway';
import * as lambda from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';

export default class ApiGatewayFunctionStack extends cdk.Stack {
  
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    
    super(scope, id, props);

    const handler = new lambda.Function(this, 'WidgetHandler', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X, // So we can use async in widget.js
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('resources'),
      handler: 'widgets.main',
    });

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'widgets-api', {
      restApiName: 'Widget Service',
      description: 'This service serves widgets.',
    });

    const getWidgetsIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(handler, {
      requestTemplates: { 'application/json': '{ "statusCode": "200" }' },
    });

    api.root.addMethod('GET', getWidgetsIntegration); // GET /
  }
}
```

The full error below seems to indicate that at least part of the issue migh be that the aws-apigateway package has its own packages that are incompatible.

I am lost as to how to resolve this, so any help is much appreciated.

```
test-deploy/ApiGatewayFunctionStack.ts:49:68 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IFunction'.
  Types of property 'role' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role").IRole | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role").IRole | undefined'.
      Type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role").IRole' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role").IRole'.
        Types of property 'grant' are incompatible.
          Type '(grantee: import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals").IPrincipal, ...actions: string[]) => import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/grant").Grant' is not assignable to type '(grantee: import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals").IPrincipal, ...actions: string[]) => import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib...'.
            Types of parameters 'grantee' and 'grantee' are incompatible.
              Type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals").IPrincipal' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/principals").IPrincipal'.
                Types of property 'addToPolicy' are incompatible.
                  Type '(statement: import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement").PolicyStatement) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(statement: import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement").PolicyStatement) => boolean'.
                    Types of parameters 'statement' and 'statement' are incompatible.
                      Type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement").PolicyStatement' is not assignable to type 'import("D:/Users/andyb/Documents/github/agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/policy-statement").PolicyStatement'.
                        Types have separate declarations of a private property 'action'.

49     const getWidgetsIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(handler, {
```

Comment: The issue goes away if I delete the /agb-aws-functions/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/node_modules folder. However, `npm i` causes this folder to reappear and cause the issue again.

Comment: The issue does seem to be that installing the @aws-cdk/aws-apigateway package creates a node_modules sub-folder containing incompatible versions of interfaces. Building on GitHub, the same error occurs and I am lost as to why this node_modules sub-folder is being created and how it might be suppressed.

Comment: can you add your package.json ? typically happens when cdk dependencies are at different versions.

Comment: take off the ^ symbols in package.json for dependencies `"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.90.0"`  to `"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "1.90.0"`, delete package-lock.json, remove node_modules and npm install one more time and try it .

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. My package.json can be found here: https://github.com/andybalham/agb-aws-functions/blob/main/package.json. I will try your suggestions later.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala thank you so much for your advice. Following it has resolved the issue.

Comment: Awesome, I added an answer, so its helpful if any one faces the same issue. You can help by [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/919289) and/or upvoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This error `Argument of type 'SomeClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISomeClass'` typically occurs when version of CDK dependencies are at different versions. To solve the issue, we need to bring all the dependencies to same version.

- Delete `node_modules` folder
- Delete `package-lock.json`
- Ensure all dependencies in package.json are using same version.
- Remove carrot ^ symbol before dependencies for example from "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.90.0" to "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "1.90.0" , to avoid different minor versions getting installed.
- `npm install`

Comment: Many thanks, man, you saved me for days of debugging, I was deleting modules and forgot to delete the package-lock.json

Comment: you save my startup!

Comment: I tried same getting : > npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: cdk@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@3.7.7
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"~3.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@">=3.8 <5.0" from ts-jest@27.0.7
npm ERR! node_modules/ts-jest
npm ERR!   dev ts-jest@"^27.0.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

Comment: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/ashishkarpe/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ashishkarpe/.npm/_logs/2021-10-29T06_36_09_516Z-debug.log

Comment: my detail issue is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732793/aws-cdk-typescript-issue-the-expected-type-comes-from-property-securitygroups?noredirect=1#comment123269657_69732793

Comment: Thanks, this was really handy for me. I was getting the error `Property 'architecture' is missing in type 'Function' but required in type 'IFunction'.` when trying to integrate `@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway` into my CDK project and I noticed that there was a version mismatch between it and the other services.

Comment: Just FYI, in the package.json file no need to change the version under `devDependencies`, only changing versions under `dependencies` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to import the package like this :

```
const lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');
```

But code quality checkers (e.g. ESLINT) may not like it.